# How to pattern match against Text without using OverloadedStrings?

Tags: string, haskell, pattern-matching

This works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
myFunc :: Text -> String
myFunc ""    = "nothing"
myFunc other = "something!"
```

Without the `OverloadedStrings` extension however, `""` is of type `String` so it doesn't compile. Using a function  like `myFunc (pack "")` is not allowed in patterns.

[Haskell Bytestrings: How to pattern match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056449/haskell-bytestrings-how-to-pattern-match) contains some suggestions that should work, however in this case I'm wondering if there is something special about the fact that it works with `OverloadedStrings` that would allow a better way?

Comment: Why avoid `OverloadedStrings`? That is exactly one of the two purposes of that extension (the other is construction of `String`-like things with nice syntax).

Comment: I'll probably end up using it, I'm just trying to understand how everything works!

Comment: You can use guards: `myFunc s | s == pack "" = "nothing" | otherwise = "something!"`.

Comment: My first version used guards. The actual case is more complicated though and is much clearer with patterns, so I'm trying to use them instead.

Comment: @melpomene One possible issue with that is that you might end up without a warning for incomplete patterns (as in the `f n | even n = ... | odd n  = ...` case).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most *direct* translation is with [ViewPatterns](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-02-view-patterns.html)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.Text as Txt
myFunc (Txt.unpack->"") = "nothing"
myFunc _other = "something!"
```

The *best* translation, albeit probably too specific for your actual use case, is of course

```
myFunc txt | Txt.null txt  = "nothing"
           | otherwise     = "something!"
```

You could also go nuts and make up a pattern synonym:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns #-}
pattern T :: String -> Txt.Text
pattern T str <- (Txt.unpack -> str)
 where T = Txt.pack
```

and then

```
myFunc (T"") = "nothing"
myFunc _other = "something"
```

Arguably, `OverloadedStrings` is a more sane extension than `ViewPatterns`, and certainly saner than `PatternSynonyms`.

Comment: I did think of `ViewPatterns` but dismissed them because I assumed the OP wanted to have an answer w\o `LANGUAGE`-extensions. But nice explanation of `ViewPatterns` and `PatternSynonyms` nevertheless (+1)

Comment: agree, though I learned about `PatternSynonyms` so accepting. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be more efficient to write `myFunc ((==) Txt.empty -> True) = "nothing"`? since I assume checking if two `Text`s are the same is faster than converting this to a `String` (especially for non-empty string).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hm might well be faster. Is `Txt.unpack` lazy?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way to solve this is to use either guards as @melpomene suggests or case expressions.

```
testfunc :: Text -> String
testfunc s | s == pack "" = "nothing"
           | otherwise    = "someting"

testfunc' :: Text -> String
testfunc' s = case unpack s of
                "" -> "nothing"
                _  -> "something"
```

The inner workings of `LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings` uses the `IsString` typeclass, if I remember correctly, and I guess it also relies on `INLINING` to make this efficient.

Comment: hadn't thought of `case`, that's a decent way to do it. Thanks!